# In multiple monitors, sub windows always opens in primary screen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window

I have WPF application, in case of multiple monitors, when Main window moved to secondary screen, all sub window opens in primary monitor only.
I have added

```
  <Window x:Class="ModalDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"              
    mc:Ignorable="d" ResizeMode="NoResize" 
    Title="{Binding DialogTitle,Mode=OneWay}"
    Height="{Binding DialogHeight,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Width="{Binding DialogWidth,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    WindowState="Normal"   
    WindowStyle="None" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
    attachedbehavior:CenterOnSizeChangeBehaviour.CenterOnSizeChange="true">
```

in subwindow xaml code, and before opening I am assigning owner as main window.

```
subWindow.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

I wanted to open sub windows where main window is.

Comment: Most likely the issue is in the order you are doing things. Can you edit your question and add the top part of the SubWindow XAML and the code part where you create your SubWindow and show it.

Comment: I dont know the solution. But to inform you, but I've tested it, and one mine it is working well. Maybe related to driver/windows.

Comment: I also tried with simple sample application where it working properly, but somehow it is not working with my Application.